# Can't open MySQL 5.5 Command Line Client

Tags: mysql, windows

Whenever I open MySQL 5.5 Command Line Client, it closes immediately:
[image]

Comment: Show link properties (command line and working directory).

Comment: You should to open `cmd` window, navigate to folder and start the client. So you will abble to look the error. Post the error here for someone can help you

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the MySQL service isn't disabled: https://mccshreyas.wordpress.com/2018/01/07/how-to-fix-mysql-command-line-crashing-problem/

Comment: I checked, it isn't disabled.